# How to use Hidden Service Authentication?

Tags: onion-services, authentication

How can [Hidden Service Authentication](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/blob/HEAD:/proposals/121-hidden-service-authentication.txt) be used? I never saw documentation about that anywhere.

Comment: Huh. I had no idea such a thing had even been considered, let alone implemented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en), there are two configuration options (i.e. things you put in your torrc):

- `HidServAuth` is what can be used on the client.  It allows you to provide authentication cookies for hidden services as in `HidServAuth <onion-address> <auth-cookie>`.
- `HiddenServiceAuthorizeClient` is the server side companion.

Protocol-related information can be found in the [rendezvous-specification](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/rend-spec.txt) at section 2.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great video example here from AdaFruit showing how to get it running on a Raspberry Pi. The links below the video have a load more useful links.  It's insanely easy.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKBKtDbhDko

Comment: Could you also expand on the source material?