# Is it safe to use shared HidServAuth with hidden service?

Tags: onion-services, anonymity, security, configuration

https://secure.sw.gs:419/aaw/publist/adblock.html

This webpage ask me to include HidServAuth to my torrc file.
However, I'm not sure that this is safe.
What will happen if someone and I connect to the same hidden service using same HidServAuth secret?

Comment: See http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/219/how-to-use-hidden-service-authentication for context. But I don't think that this is a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe. The auth cookie is just tor-level authentication. It doesn't divulge anything about your identity.